# Search and Replace Regex possibilities to add <beg> and </end> tags to each line:

Tags: regex, ide, editor, replace

I was wondering my options people know of for adding tags to each line.

Say I have 100 items I need to put in a string array

```
<resources>
    <string-array>
    item001
    item002
    item003
        ...
    </string-array>
</resources>
```

What I need is to somehow wrap each line or each line with the items in it like:

```
<resources>
    <string-array>
    <item>item001</item>
    <item>item002</item>
    <item>item003</item>
        ...
    </string-array>
</resources>
```

I'd appreciate a solution achievable on your average Linux box. No windows/osx please. Thanks!

Comment: FYI, I'm using Eclipse for Android development.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as you wanted, awk solution under **Linux**

```
awk '!/<.*>/ && $0{gsub(/^[ \t]+/,"",$0);$0="<item>"$0"</item>"}1' yourXml
```

test with your snippet:

```
kent$  echo "<resources>
    <string-array>
    item001
    item002
    item003
        ...
    </string-array>
</resources>
"|awk '!/<.*>/ && $0{gsub(/^[ \t]+/,"",$0);$0="<item>"$0"</item>"}1'
```

**output**

```
<resources>
    <string-array>
<item>item001</item>
<item>item002</item>
<item>item003</item>
<item>...</item>
    </string-array>
</resources>
```

Answer (score 1):

Select regular expressions checkbox in Eclipse 'Find and Replace' dialog and then replace

```
(^\s*)([^<\r\n]+$)
```

with

```
\1<item>\2<\item>
```

Comment: Ok, that's good to know. Thanks, but I may have mislead by giving the example item001, 002, 003. Actually, each line has random text...not sequential in any way. Any way to use regex for every line?